# Force.com IDE Default Proposals

Tags: force.com, ide

while working on visualforce pages, i am not able to see proposals for available properties on different tags using CTRL + SPACE. does this need to be setup separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is still under development. It previously existed in older versions (I believe as late as API v29 or so), but it was disabled when the IDE went open source. They are planning on re-introducing this feature in a future release, although nobody has an answer as to when.

Answer (score 2):

No there are not much options to configure in Force.com IDE. But I would suggest you to log and issue or ask for enhancement over to IDE Project team :-) .. Force.com IDE has been made Open Source last year.

[Force.com IDE Source Project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore)